# Can I have a SharePoint Online list validate a lookup field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, validation, powerapp

I am doing testing on SharePoint Online. I have a list with the below schema:

[image: screenshot of various list columns]

As you can see, there's a lookup field: `Document type`

In this `document type`, currently there're 2 values: "HKID" and "Passport"

And the desired validation formula is:

```
If "Document type" = "HKID"
   Visit date < "2020-01-01"
Else if "Document type" = "Passport"
   Visit date >= "2020-01-01"
```

But the lookup field isn't there:

[image: Screenshot of Validation view with the lookup column missing from the "Insert Column" box]

Does SharePoint Online support this kind of logic/validation?

Or I can set it in the form in PowerApps?

Answer (score 2):

For now, SharePoint Online list validation does not support lookup column. If you need that, You may need to use Power Apps.

You can start from here:
https://techwizard.cloud/2020/02/08/powerapps-sharepoint-online-list-field-validation/